# Color Renderer in JTable if it is non editable field?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have 3 columns in JTable. One column is editable. Other columns are non-editable. Editable column should be displayed green color and non-editable column should be in red color. I have tried with `DefaultRenderer` class but its not working. Please if anyone know this, help me.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are few ways to do this. Following <sup>[1](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/Stripe.html)</sup> will render the column 1 as grey.

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                                     int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, vColIndex);
        if (vColIndex == 0) {//if first column
            c.setBackground(Color.red);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

Or you can have class override `DefaultTableCellRenderer` like following <sup>[2](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/CustomCellRenderer.shtml)</sup>

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object obj, 
                         boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, 
                            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (column == 0){
            cell.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else{
            cell.setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i have used the second only..i have invoked like table.setDefaulRenderer(Color.class,new CustomTableCellRenderer()); ..but its not working..